# Consider $3$ positive real numbers $a,b,c$.Show that there cannot exist two distinct positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that both...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $3$ positive real numbers $a,b,c$.Show that there cannot exist two distinct positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that both $a^m+b^m=c^m$ and $a^n+b^n=c^n$
My work:
$a^m+b^m=c^m$
$(a^m+b^m)c^{n-m}=c^n$
So,now we have,
$(a^m+b^m)c^{n-m}=(a^n+b^n)$
Now, I cannot do anything. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a^m+b^m=c^m$ then clearly $a<c$ and $b<c$. Now if $n>m$ this implies 
$c^{n-m}>a^{n-m}$ and $c^{n-m}>b^{n-m}$, hence
$$c^n= c^{n-m}c^m=c^{n-m}a^m+c^{n-m}b^m>a^{n-m}a^m+b^{n-m}b^m=a^n+b^n.$$